# How to prevent the same result from appearing multiple times in a subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I am working in a dataset that I have captured and brought to MySQL tables for analysis. We do not have the source code for the original software, and pulled our data down using an API.

In this dataset, there are jobs which are invoiced. Unfortunately, the original developers did not tie the invoice to the job in any way. Both are related to customers, and (we are hoping) that the dollars match. There are thousands of each. I am trying to write a SQL that contains fields from Job and Invoice, using a sub select to carefully choose which invoice to retrieve with the criteria of the sub select as follows:

(SELECT Invoices.Invoice_ID FROM Invoices Invoices.Customer_id = Job.Customer_id AND Invoices.Invoice_Date > Job.Completion_Date ORDER by Invoices.Invoice_Date ASC LIMIT 1);

What I am trying to also do, is restrict the sub-select so that each job and each invoice appear only one time in the result set. I do not know how to do it. I do not want an invoice to show up for two jobs if the criteria is very similar. Two jobs may be identical as the services are recurring (such as cleaning a pool). If two jobs occur with the same amount and same customer, but there is only one invoice before both jobs, the same invoice shows up in the sub select column twice. Any ideas on how I can ask MySQL to exclude from the sub select results already returned?

If not, I will have to have application code run this one by one and build an array of WHERE Invoices.Invoice_ID NOT IN (..., ..., ...).

I have tried assigning Invoiced a table name:

```
 FROM Invoices Inv ... AND Invoices.Invoice_ID not in (SELECT Invoice_ID FROM Inv)
```

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: This is likely very easy to solve, but would be better if you provided formatted sample data and desired output rather than a story that contributes to TLDR.

Answer (score 0):

My deduction from your post is that you're likely looking for a Top N per Group type of problem. [Lateral/Left Join Lateral](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) is what you're going for here.

I would strongly encourage you to post sample data and expected results so we know exactly what you are asking.

```
SELECT Invoices.Invoice_ID, Job.*
FROM Invoices 
LATERAL (
   SELECT Job.CustomerId, Job.Completion_Date, Job.*
   FROM Job
   WHERE
      Invoices.Customer_id = Job.Customer_id AND 
      Invoices.Invoice_Date > Job.Completion_Date
   ORDER BY Job.Completion_Date --if needed?
   LIMIT 1
) Job;
```